# Extract all images from an external site [Node.js]

Tags: node.js, httprequest

I'm working in a code that takes all the images from a website, then send that images as a String to the browser, but doesn't works!

I'm trying to use the http module to create a server, get the principal page of pinterest, match all the images tags, store each match in an Array and finally send it.

This is the code:

```
var http = require('http')
  , options = {
        host: 'www.pinterest.com'
      , port: 80
      , path: '/'
      , method: 'GET'
    }
  , images = [ ]
  ;


http.createServer( function ( request, response ) {

  http.request( options, function ( res ) {
    res.setEncoding( 'utf8' );
    res.on( 'data', function ( chunk ) {

      matches.push( chunk.match(/<img[^>]+src="([^">]+)/g) );

    });
  }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
  });

  response.writeHead( 200, { 'Content-Type' : 'text/html' } );

  response.end( images.toString() );

}).listen(8888);
```

I don't have any error in the console, but after one minute, the console prints:

`problem with request: socket hang up`

Comment: Is the end client's request fulfilled, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have a problem with your regex. Anyway, this method will bring you the data:

```
var http = require('http')
  , options = {
    host: 'pinterest.com'
  , port: 80
  , path: '/'
  , method: 'GET'
}
  , images = [ ];

http.createServer( function ( request, response ) {


var req = http.get(options, function(res){
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        images.push( chunk.match(/<img[^>]+src="([^">]+)/g) );
    }).on('end', function(){
        response.writeHead( 200, { 'Content-Type' : 'text/javascript' } );
        response.end(images.toString());
    });
});

req.on('error', function(error){
    console.log('error: ' + error.message);
    response.writeHead( 200, { 'Content-Type' : 'text/html' } );
    response.end('error: ' + error.message);
});

}).listen(8888);
```

I used here the `http.get` method instead of the `http.request`

Comment: Thanks friend, but now throw an alert box with this error:
Windows Script Host

Comands Sequence: C:\Program Files\nodejs\images\image.js
Line: 1
Character: 1
Error: Object excepted
Code: 800A138F
Origin: Microsoft JScript Runtime Error

Comment: Try this article, http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-800a138f-errors.html

Comment: Oh, god!
I'm trying to run the code without the node command; sorry.

Comment: @udidu , how do you call this app from client , do you just write some dummy page which calls this server on this port ??

Comment: After running the server go to http://local host:8888, since we didn't define routes only the root is accessible

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have already resolved your problem, trying with the package [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) is much easier.
It's the best jQuery-like package for Node I've ever seen, it's very complete.

You would load the remote HTML and then filter the images, for example...

```
var imageUrl = $("img").attr("src");
```

Also, parsing the HTML in the `data` event may give you chunks of the tag, which is a problem.